# Microsoft Graph and redirect_uri http instead of https

Tags: azure, redirect, graph, asp.net-core-mvc

I trying to authenticate with Microsoft Graph 2 using ASP.Net Core (MVC).

The AzureAd settings:

```
"AzureAd": {
"Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
"TenantId": "common",
"CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"  }
```

The site url is like

> https://mysite

Then I was redirected to the login url:

> https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?...

but the redirect_uri, in the url parameters, does not include the https

> https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=****&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmysite%2Fsignin-oidc

I was trying to force the using of HTTPS but I can´t find it

Upate:

The application is deployed in Linux.

Any suggestion?

Comment: what is the `Redirect Uri` configured for your application under AD App Registration? all redirect URIs would start as https, except for desktop app [platform].

Comment: Yes, all start with https https://XXXX.azurewebsites.net/signin-oidc

Comment: can you the answer given in this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45946960/azure-http-to-https-redirect-not-working-for-spa), though yours is MVC app.

Comment: follow the suggestions in this thread https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/issues/115#issuecomment-901335913

Comment: thanks, this thread is the solution. The specific answer [link](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/issues/115#issuecomment-921854490)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding in dockerfile:

```
ENV ASPNETCORE_FORWARDEDHEADERS_ENABLED=true
```

it works for me like comment Anand´s link